# Как замокать статический метод FileUtils.copyURLToFile() в Junit 5?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mock

У меня есть метод, в котором я обращаюсь к статическому методу:

```
File file = new File(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        try {
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(faceSetVisitorDto.getPhotoLink()), file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return;
        }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно замокать метод FileUtils.copyURLToFile() в Junit 5

Answer (score 0):

Для этого потребуется `mockito-inline`, для gradle - `testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.6.0'` и `mockito` должен быть >= 3.4.0

Ну и сам кусок теста:

```
try (MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(FileUtils.class)) {
    mocked.when(FileUtils::copyURLToFile).thenReturn("То что нужно");
    mocked.when(() -> FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(faceSetVisitorDto.getPhotoLink()), file)).thenReturn("То что нужно");

    assertEquals("То что нужно", FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(faceSetVisitorDto.getPhotoLink()), file));
}
```

Вроде достаточно наглядно

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Только вот FileUtils.copyURLToFile() ничего не возвращает, а обычная конструкция с doNothing() не работает. Мне нужно чтобы во время теста, вызов этого метода игнорировался, так как ему нужна валидная ссылка на файл.

Comment: @Aleksey `FileUtils.copyURLToFile()` должен возвращать то, что указано в `thenReturn()`. Не очень понял что за метод `doNothing()` и какой метод должен игнорироваться

Comment: Метод `FileUtils.copyURLToFile()`  это `void` метод и конструкция `thenReturn()` к нему не применима (возможно конечно я не знаю каких-то приемов, когда это можно сделать). Для `void` методов используют `doNothing()` это означает, что при вызове этого метода он будет игнорироваться. В моем случае это как раз то что мне нужно, так как во время теста при вызове метода `FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL source, File destination)` вылетает `UnknownHostException`. Только вот `doNothing()` в стандартной реализации не работает со статическими методами. Вопрос в том, как сделать чтобы работало)